# Resize axes to fit image

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

How can I resize my axes on a matlab GUI to fit exactly with the size of the image I just resized?

I have this:

```
I = imread('honolulu.png');

I = imresize(im2double(I), [600, 700]);
```

After that I am drawing a grid on the pictures, but because the axes size is different the grid does not look good. However, if I create a figure and I do it on a figure outside the GUI it looks perfect.
Full code:

```
%Load map

I = imread('honolulu.png');

%Resize image to be multiple of 50 in each axis.
I = imresize(im2double(I), [600, 700]);

%Draw grid of 50x50 pixels.
I(50:50:end, :, :) = 255;
I(:, 50:50:end, :) = 255;
axes(handles.axes1);
h = handles.axes1;imshow(I);

while (ishandle(h))
    try
        [x, y] = ginput(1);
    catch me
        %break loop in case image is closed.
        break;
    end

    %Compute top left coordinate of block clicked.
    x0 = floor((x-1)/50)*50;
    y0 = floor((y-1)/50)*50;

    %Set block RGB to random color.
    I(y0+1:y0+50-1, x0+1:x0+50-1, 1) = rand();
    I(y0+1:y0+50-1, x0+1:x0+50-1, 2) = rand();
    I(y0+1:y0+50-1, x0+1:x0+50-1, 3) = rand();

    imshow(I);
end
% Choose default command line output for city_planning
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

How it looks vs how it is supposed to look

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you be more specific?  How are you drawing a grid?  An example  image would be helpful.

Comment: @ConfusinglyCuriousTheThird Updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines are disappearing as the plot window changes size - something of an aliasing/rendering issue I guess.  Elsewhere other people have asked similar questions without a great answer.

The best I've found is setting the initial magnification to 100% and then preventing resizing.  Here's a similar example:

```
close all;
clear all;
clc; 

I = imread('peppers.png');
I = imresize(im2double(I), [600, 700]);

%Draw grid of 50x50 pixels.
I(50:50:end, :, :) = 1;
I(:, 50:50:end, :) = 1;


h = imshow(I,'initialMagnification',100);
set(gcf,'Resize','off')

%%
while (ishandle(h))
    try
        [x, y] = ginput(1);
    catch me
        %break loop in case image is closed.
        break;
    end

    %Compute top left coordinate of block clicked.
    x0 = floor((x-1)/50)*50;
    y0 = floor((y-1)/50)*50;

    %Set block RGB to random color.
    I(y0+1:y0+50-1, x0+1:x0+50-1, 1) = rand();
    I(y0+1:y0+50-1, x0+1:x0+50-1, 2) = rand();
    I(y0+1:y0+50-1, x0+1:x0+50-1, 3) = rand();

    h = imshow(I);
end
```

Comment: The answer works. But, when I close the window for some reason I get an error that starts with Error using guidata (line 87)
H must be the handle to a figure or figure descendent.

Comment: what is the condition/behavior you're implementing with the while loop?

Comment: I can't do that because I am using a global variable. The while is used to let the user click on a box of the grid and change its color

Comment: the code may need to be adapted for your purpose (I didn't define handles, and don't know how you've defined it).  I know the while loop allows multiple clicks, but under what condition would you like it to exit exactly?